# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page, admin login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, error

I keep getting Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page when i try to login into my admin account in the back-end.

I have, cleared all my cache both in **magento_root/var/cache** and in my browser i also have deleted the cookie path and domain **web/cookie/cookie_path** values in **core_config_data** table

I removed the data in **var/sessions** also as its a website currently in staging the last thing i did was install a blog plugin AW Blog and it worked with no errors and the last time i logged in successfully was last night so 12 hours ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem's a force in a change/reset of the username and password fixed the problem, after i changed the password i flushed cache again like stated in the original question and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this, Hope It's helpful for you.**

> The problem was the server configuration, i've change the
>   **max_input_vars parameter** and the message dissapeared. I saw the
>   solution in
>   http://www.webcroppers.com/magento-invalid-form-key-please-refresh-the-page/

Comment: Unfortunatly had no effect for me